# Append letters to duplicated values in a dataframe

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I'm working with a dataframe that has a column (ID) contains IDs for a bunch of projects. Unfortunately, some of these IDs are duplicated (but the projects are not).

I'm looking to make the IDs for the duplicate values unique by adding (.a, .b, .c, etc) to the end of them. I can't use numbers (or the make.unique function) because the IDs have numbers at the end which could be confusing.

I currently have the below but it gives every ID an appended letter. Is there anything I can add  so that it only impacts the duplicated IDs?

`df$ID <- ave(df$ID, df$ID, FUN = function(i) paste0(i, '.', letters[1:20]))`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need a condition that checks the `length` before `paste`ing

```
ave(df$ID, df$ID, FUN = function(i) 
    if(length(i) > 1) {
    i[-1] <- paste0(i[-1], '.', letters[seq(length(i[-1]))]); i} else i)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own version of `make.unique`:

```
my_make_unique = function(x) {
  if(length(x) > 27) stop("Too many values to make unique with single letters!")
  paste0(x, c("", paste0(".", letters[1:(length(x) - 1)])))
}

## test it
my_make_unique(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3))
# [1] "1"   "1.a" "1.b" "2.c" "2.d" "3.e"
## looks good
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could perhaps to use make.unique and replace the digit for the letter, but if this suits your case highly depends on the structure of your ID's. I assume you have no dots in the ID's for example.

```
ids <- as.character(c(1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,4))

r <- letters[as.numeric(str_extract(make.unique(ids), "(?<=\\.)(\\d*$)"))]
i <- which(!is.na(r))
ids[i] <- paste(ids[i], r[i], sep = ".")

ids

[1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "1.a" "1.b" "1.c" "2.a" "3.a" "4"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `row_number` to do this by each group in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    ID = as.character(ID), # only necessary if ID is numeric
    ID = ifelse(row_number() > 1, paste0(ID, ".", letters[row_number()]), ID),
    .by = ID)
```

**Output**

```
   ID
1   1
2 1.b
3 1.c
4   2
5 2.b
6   3
```